# How to copy derived classes when we dont know which classes are?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Assume that we have these classes:

```
class BaseClass;//im an abstract base class!
class Derived1 : public BaseClass;
class Derived2 : public BaseClass;
```

Both classes inherit from `BaseClass`, then we have one vector of pointers to BaseClass's

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> classes;
```

So now imagine that I want to copy the vector ACTUALLY COPYING THE ELEMENTS OF IT to `classes_copy`. So I don't want the pointers of the `classes_copy` to point to the same as `classes`. I want to create (using `new` to allocate, and I will free them later) a new version of everyone. We have one problem here: we don't know if that pointers of `BaseClass` points to the `Derived1` or the `Derived2` class. So, is this possible? If not, what to do? Any suggestions?